# Can't add 1 to a number i get from local storage

Tags: javascript

I have some variables like XP or currentHp and they increase by 1 in certain points,
normally they work well but when i set them to local storage and then get them, at the points they should've increase by 1, they add 1 to the end of the number. For example if XP = 4 and you save the game then load your save, when you gain +1 XP it goes like 41, 411... not 5, 6... Why does this happen? How can i fix it? I save and load XP like this;

```
localStorage.setItem("XP", XP);
XP= localStorage.getItem("XP");
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("XP", "XP");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values saved to `localStorage` are always saved as strings. You'll need to parse them as numbers before performing any arithmetic. Try this:

```js
const oldXp = 4;
localStorage.setItem("XP", oldXp);
const xp = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("XP"));
const newXp = xp + 1;
console.log(newXp); // 5 not "41"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json.parse`
LINK
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

Adding `+` to `XP= localStorage.getItem("XP");` will convert the value to number. Then you may get the desired result. Otherwise JS treats it as a string.

Finally your code should look like:
`XP= +localStorage.getItem("XP");`

Answer (score 1):

When you save number in localstroage its type gets changed into string and on retrieving back it gives you number value as string so its concats result instead of adding.

You can use any existing method to convert string into number or simply put + sign before number like below

```
const oldXp = 4;
localStorage.setItem("XP", oldXp);
const v = localStorage.getItem("XP")
const newVal = (+v) + 1
console.log(newVal)  // result will be 5
```